# Empty Form Field Validation Issues - Cannot Write Into Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I am following a tutorial from W3schools which checks for empty entries in a form then displays the errors next to each field e.g. if a user omits their forename and surname beside each filed "enter your forename" and "enter your surname" is displayed.

What they don't explain is how then to write the data into a table. I know how to do this but I cannot get it working with their script.

Here's the full code. Sorry for the confusion.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connect.php";
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$fnameErr = $snameErr = $unameErr = $passwordErr = $emailErr = "";
$forename = $surname = $username = $password = $email = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["forename"]))
     {$fnameErr = "Enter your forename";}
   else
     {$forename = validate_input($_POST["forename"]);}
   if (empty($_POST["surname"]))
     {$snameErr = "Enter your surname";}
   else
     {$surname = validate_input($_POST["surname"]);}
   if (empty($_POST["username"]))
     {$unameErr = "Enter a username";}
   else
     {$username = validate_input($_POST["username"]);}
   if (empty($_POST["password"]))
     {$passwordErr = "Enter a password";}
   else
     {$password = validate_input($_POST["password"]);}
   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
     {$emailErr = "Enter your email address";}
   else
     {$email = validate_input($_POST["email"]);}
}
function validate_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
else {
$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_2 VALUES ('0','".mysql_escape_string('forename')."','".mysql_escape_string("surname")."', '".mysql_escape_string("username")."', '".mysql_escape_string("password")."', '".mysql_escape_string("email")."')";
if(mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)){
$message = "You have successfully registered";
header("Location: register.php?message=$message");
}else{
$message = "You've Broke It!";
die(mysql_error());
header("Location: register.php?message=$message");
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/contact.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Voltaire' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />

</head>

<div class="container">

<form action="register.php? method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend><span class="formheading">Registration Form</span></legend>
<div class="form">

<div><p class="formtext">Please enter your forename</p><label for="forename">Forename</label><input id="forename" class="inset" name="forename" type="text">
<?php echo $fnameErr;?>
</div>
<div><p class="formtext">Please enter your surname</p><label for="surname">Surname</label><input id="surname" class="inset" name="surname" type="text">
<?php echo $snameErr;?></div>
<div><p class="formtext">Please enter a username</p><label for="username">Username</label><input id="username" class="inset" name="username" type="text"></div>
<?php echo $usernameErr;?>
<div><p class="formtext">Please enter a password</p><label for="password">Password</label><input id="password" class="inset" name="password" type="text"></div>
<?php echo $passwordErr;?>
<div><p class="formtext">Please enter your e-mail address</p><label for="email">email address</label><input id="email" class="inset" name="email" type="text">
<?php echo $emailErr;?></div>

<div class="submit"><input name="Submit" type="Submit" class="submitbtn" value="Submit" /></div>
<div class="submit"><input name="Reset" type="Reset" class="resetbtn" value="Reset"/></div>

</div>
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't insert with aconrad insert statement but got it working with this.

```
$Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
$Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_2 VALUES ('0','".mysql_escape_string($forename)."','".mysql_escape_string($surname)."', '".mysql_escape_string($username)."', '".mysql_escape_string($password)."', '".mysql_escape_string($email)."')";
```

If I enter :

```
forename
surname
username
password
```

But do not enter anything in the email field then click submit the errors are displayed but all fields are cleared and the user has to re-enter all the information. How do I prevent this from happening i.e. how do I  keep the data that has been entered?

Comment: could you please tell us what error you give?

Comment: You forgot to define the columns you want to insert to.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in register2.php on line 37 which is :

    else {

Answer (score 0):

You must name the columns you have.

Since i dont know the names im guessing but change them to match your column names in the database. Like this

```
Query = "INSERT INTO $Table_2 
(Id,ForName,SureName,UserName,PassWord,Email) 
VALUES ('0','".mysql_escape_string($formValue['forename'])."',
'".mysql_escape_string($formValue["surname"])."', 
'".mysql_escape_string($formValue["username"])."', 
'".mysql_escape_string($formValue["password"])."', 
'".mysql_escape_string($formValue["email"])."');";
```

Notice `(Id,ForName,SureName,UserName,PassWord,Email)`

Answer (score 0):

unless i am missing something, your structure doesn't work because of your outer if/else

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

}

else {

}
```

all of your database stuff is inside the else, which only goes through if the request method is NOT post. if your form method is post, then that means you're trying to do your sql stuff with no data.

i would move your outer else into an if/else inside your first if so that it's more like

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(isset($_POST['pick a field']))
    {
        //your validation stuff here
        //your database code here
    }
    else
    {
        //some error about not having valid info
    }
}
```

an outer else is probably not needed

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="register.php? method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

you need it as:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also that else; causes errors.

if you use else;
script would go into a infinite loop because the query would run
every time as it is not in the if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") loop.

The query executes, with all the values empty. 
Your table should have LOOOOTS of blank records.

It executes ok, it redirects to the same page, executes query, redirects, executes and so on.

Check for post using if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) not just ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

Here is the script, changed so that it works:

http://pastie.org/private/c7zqeeemtxdt2q85uo8jw

Comment: Thank you very much. It's almost working. I'm getting an insert error because the first field in my database is an auto incrementing primary key field named id. I tired :

FIELD_ID = '".mysql_real_escape_string('0', $Link)."'

Which gave :

Query was: INSERT INTO VALUES ('0','','', '', '', ''). Error:

Comment: use NULL instead of '0' if you really-really dont want to specify the field names in the query. If you specify the fields, just skip ID.

Answer (score -1):

You have a " else; " ... should it be else { ?
A full code list would help.

You may want to use insert like INSERT INTO table SET field=value, this way it will be easier to match columns with values.

```
INSERT INTO $Table_2 
SET 
Id = 0
ForName = '".mysql_escape_string($formValue['forename'])."'
SureName = '".mysql_escape_string(
//etc.
```

see [mysql insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Comment: @anonrad I don't know if I need else either! If I remove it I get :

This webpage has a redirect loop

In chrome and in firefox

The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: added another answer with all the data